# Mysql Query - Get row value based on column name in a different table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One for inventory and one for information about inventory items.

The info table caries much more information about a website and I would like to keep all the info in one table.

```
INVENTORY TABLE

UserID--ITEM1--ITEM2--ITEM3

key1--qty--qty--qty

key2--qty--qty--qty
```

Table2 structure "info table"

```
  ItemClass  --   ItemID   --  Info

   CLASS1    --   ITEM1    --  "best item ever info"

   CLASS1    --   ITEM2    --   "worst item ever info"

   CLASS9    --   ITEM3    --  "some other item info"
```

I'm trying to get a single query to grab `CLASS1` rows where `ItemID` matches a column name in `Table1` if the qty is above 0 and the `key = $a`

Any help generating this query would be a life saver. I do not want to redo my inventory schema. Thanks for looking!

Comment: You should really normalize your schema. If you need to match item IDs, they should be values, not column names, so you can join on them.

Comment: Well, this is a user specific inventory system. Each user may have any number of a huge list of items. I can't imagine a different 2 table design. Perhaps I can't call a query this way. My inventory list will be ever growing.

Comment: The inventory table should have columns `userID`, `itemID`, `quantity`.

Comment: If the inventory table had userID then each user would just have a copy of every item in the database. Wouldn't replicating that much data be wasteful?

Comment: Each user would only have items that belong to them.

Comment: There's no replication. The Inventory table just has an item ID, all the information about the item is in the Info table, and it just appears once for each item.

Comment: Please, get a textbook on relational database design and learn about normalization. This is very standard technology.

Comment: Perhaps I have gone about setting up the db wrong. My "game" will have lets say 400 items. They do not have any dynamic values i.e. health/enchantments. Each player will eventually acquire many of each of these items. Keeping a userID as a column in my inventory seems wasteful.

Comment: Ok well thanks for your help Barmar.

Comment: You're not the first to think that. But you're wrong. It's the proper way to design databases. It's wrong to make a separate column for each item, because it means you have to recode all your queries whenever you add a new item.

Comment: Reading up on normalization I understand what I did wrong. Thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT info.*
FROM info
JOIN Inventory ON (ItemID = 'ITEM1' AND ITEM1 > 0)
               OR (ItemID = 'ITEM2' AND ITEM2 > 0)
               OR (ItemID = 'ITEM3' AND ITEM3 > 0)
WHERE info.ItemClass = 'CLASS1'
AND Inventory.userID = $a
```

Comment: Inventory table caries the userID. Could i just swap out info.userID for inventory.userID?